# Frozen insertion in parallel transaction

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc, concurrency, spring-data-jpa

I have two transactions with shareable count down latch. Each transaction is performed in separate thread. I need such mechanism to reproduce "dirty read" situation. 
The first transaction do update of "target entity" and flush changes without commit, then I set thread to waiting state (countDownLatch).

In the second transaction I fetch "target entity" and copy dirty field to another entity and do save. After save operation I make countDown to continue the first transaction and rollback it.

Below the code samples of transaction methods.
The first:

```
@Transactional
public void updatePrice() {
    log.info("Start price updating. Thread '{}'", Thread.currentThread().getName());
    Collection<Product> products = productRepository.findAll();
    products.forEach(this::updatePrice);
    productRepository.saveAll(products);
    entityManager.flush();
    log.info("Flash changes and wait for order transaction");
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error("Something wrong");
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    log.error("Rollback changes");
    throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected exception");

}
```

The second: I have main service  that is bounded by transaction and wrapper service on it to count down the latch.

Wrapper:

```
public void doOrder(Long productId, Long amount) {
    log.info("Start do order. Thread '{}'", Thread.currentThread().getName());
    orderService.doOrder(productId, amount);
    log.info("Order transaction committed");
    latch.countDown();
    log.info("Finish order process");
}
```

Main service:

```
@Transactional
public void doOrder(Long productId, Long amount) {
    Product product = productRepository.findById(productId).get();
    log.info("Get product");
    Order order = Order.builder().price(product.getPrice()).amount(amount).productId(new Long(productId)).build();
    orderRepository.save(order);
    log.info("Save order");
}
```

So, at the line

> orderRepository.save(order);

the thread has became frozen. I see only insert statement in the logs.

But if I remove relation between 'order' and 'product', the insert doesn't become frozen.
I guess that there is deadlock on 'product' and countDownLatch. But this issue occurs only with mysql jdbc. If I switch onto postgres jdbc,  then no issue there.

PS:
The first transaction executes following queries:

```
select * from product;
update product set price = ...
```

The second one executes:

```
select * from product where id = ...;
insert into product_order(product_id, amount, price) values (...)
```

Comment: Every database vendor implements different strategies for locking. If you provide the exact statements that get executed somebody might be able to explain what exactly is locked and why. Also, databases offer information about what is locked that you can query. This question seems to have some useful answers: https://serverfault.com/questions/36260/how-can-i-show-mysql-locks

Comment: I've updated the question with queries